# How can I build a mixed-columns form in PHP using bootstrap 3?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a 1 column form in bootstrap with some rows sharing a second column. It's for making an employee profile editing page in an intranet so I don't really care about medium or small screen sizes.

I'm trying to make it using an example I found [here](http://www.bootply.com/pppeater/jrNvaahcOh) but the result is not what I need. I'm used to work with CSS style sheets but to be honest, bootstrap grid system always confuses me.

Here's a mockup of what I need:

[image: What I need]

and here's what I'm getting:

[image: What I have]

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputLabel3" class="col-md-4 control-label">Label 3:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="img-preview img-preview-sm">
            <img src="<?php echo EMPLOYEE_IMG_URL; ?>/1.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: HTML does not match the layout you show. So what are we supposed to do with it

Comment: Yes, the HTML has a 3rd column but that's not the case here... because no matter how many columns I have, from the second row afterwards they all get pushed down until the image ends.

Answer (score 0):

for first 4 inputs and image you have to create row divided into two columns (col-md-6)
for left col set inputs with col-12 
for right col set the image